# Ubuntu 22.04 (Gnome)- unable to find or remove Dolphin's KDE-wallet

Tags: networking, kde, password, directory, dolphin

I recently installed Dolphin on my Ubuntu 22.04 (With Gnome) and seem **to prefer it to Nautilus or Nemo**, at least for managing network folders and files.
But Dolphin kept *suggesting* that I protect my files **with KDE-Wallet.**  Finally I  supplied a couple of passwords to it- Um, "late at night"...
Guess what?  I've forgotten the passwords...
How do I find them, or at least deactivate this whole wallet nonsense, and just use dolphin?